# Run a db script using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, oracle11g, jenkins-plugins

I need to run a db script to take oracle database backup in a remote server using Jenkins in Windows environment. Is it possible? I created a Free style project in Jenkins and installed SQLPlus script runner plugin. But it didn't work. Can anyone please advise me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple shell or python script to run from jenkins then you can do it like this :

```
Configure jenkins job to run as shell script
and write something like 
#!/bin/sh
sh <location_of_shell_script_for_backup>
```

You can change **sh** as per your requirement.